# MPDF - Performance Issue

Tags: php, mpdf

I use mpdf to generate invoice.

It's perfect but very slow.

To do 80 invoices (tables and one barcode) the generate take 122s !!!

If I just comment the line `$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);` it's take 5s, of course no pdf generated.

I use mpdf_compress.php and add this line :

```
$mpdf->useSubstitutions=false; 
$mpdf->simpleTables = true;
```

It's possible to increase the execution ? Or do I need to change the library ?

Thanks

Comment: can u post the complete code of mpdf

Comment: are u on any MVC? or core php?

Comment: Please have a look here [mPDF - Slow!](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/slow.html): "Tables - the more rows and columns the worse it gets". So what is a "complex html table"? ;) Do you use big tables? I think all or at least the most PHP-PDF libraries have those performance "issues" with tables and/or image processing. E.g. [TCPDF twice as slow as FPDF with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285314/tcpdf-twice-as-slow-as-fpdf-with-same-code) ... mPDF is based on both and HTML2PDF. Does the barcode take long or is it within the 5 seconds?

Comment: Hi, it's exactly the the page I see (https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/slow.html). 5s is without WriteHtml so whitout barcode generation too

Comment: To post code is difficult, I create a class extend mpdf to create invoice with array of order and html template